# DB in the EC2 on the private subnet. How connect without bastion host?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have a VPC with a public and a private subnet. In the private subnet I have a EC2 instance without a public ip. The EC2 instance is connected to the Internet with a NAT Gateway. Ok.

In the EC2 I want install a database.

In my local machine I installed the AWS-CLI and the SSM plugin, with SSM i can connect to the machine without problem

```
aws ssm start-session --target <instanceID>
```

Now I want connect to the EC2 with SSH/SCP and with a DB Tools like  Datagrip.

It's possibile without a Bastion Host in the public subnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible as SSM supports tunneling:

- [Session Manager launches tunneling support for SSH and SCP](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/07/session-manager-launches-tunneling-support-for-ssh-and-scp/)